# How to query all records instead of .all() in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Now that `ActiveRecord::Relation#all` is deprecated in Rails 4, how do I iterate over all records?

Previously:

```
Foo.all.each do |foo|
  # whatever
end
```

I can approximate it now like this, but it feels dirty:

```
Foo.where(true).each do |foo|
  # whatever
end
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 76):

According to the [Rails Guide on Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects), the correct way to iterate through all records is by using [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each).

Using `Foo.all.each` will load the **entire** table into memory, instantiating all the rows; then iterate through the instances. `find_each` does this in batches, which is more efficient in terms of memory usage.

From the guide:

> The `find_each` method retrieves a batch of records and then yields *each* record to the block individually as a model. In the following example, `find_each` will retrieve 1000 records (the current default for both `find_each` and `find_in_batches`) and then yield each record individually to the block as a model. This process is repeated until all of the records have been processed:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  NewsLetter.weekly_deliver(user)
end
```

References:

- [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)
- [ActiveRecord::Batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html)

Comment: It probably doesn't, but does using `find_each` reduce the number of queries?

Answer (score 18):

yes, `Foo.all`.

`all` is deprecated on an ActiveRecord::Relation (eg. `Foo.where(true)`), not on ActiveRecord::Base.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all

Comment: Aha, I guess the deprecation warnings are getting it wrong then.  I'm being warned wherever I'm using Foo.all

Comment: you may have to elaborate more on the code you're using and the warning you're getting, then.

Comment: It appears that "they" set where(true) so it now crashes in later Rails4.x versions.  Error: "RuntimeError: unsupported: TrueClass".  Why let something work for others, if it annoys your sensibilities?  Just force it down everyone's throat and let them loose hundreds of their life-hours searching for the problems you created for them on purpose.

Answer (score 13):

Release notes for Rails 4:

> Model.all now returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, rather than an array
>   of records. Use Relation#to_a if you really want an array.

So your code will look like this:

```
Foo.all.to_a.each do |foo|
  # whatever
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an incorrect deprecation warning somewhere in Rails.  As of Rails 4.0.2 the warning message still exists.  I get the following error when I try and run Foo.all:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to
>   eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. `Post.where(published:
>   true).load`). If you want to get an array of records from a relation,
>   you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).to_a`).

I'm almost 100% certain I watched in a RailsCasts that #all was being changed to return an Relation in Rails 4 (instead of an array) - no mention of deprecation.