# Query Optimization with ActiveRecord for each method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, optimization

Below mentioned query is taking too much time, not able to understand how to optimized it.

Code and Associations :

```
temp = []
platforms = current_user.company.advisory_platforms
platforms.each{ |x| temp << x.advisories.published.collect(&:id) }

class Advisory
  has_many :advisory_platforms,:through =>:advisory_advisory_platforms
end

class AdvisoryPlatform
  has_many :companies,:through => :company_advisory_platforms
  has_many :company_advisory_platforms,:dependent => :destroy
  has_many :advisory_advisory_platforms,:dependent => :destroy
  has_many :advisories, :through => :advisory_advisory_platforms
end
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Tried temp = platforms.includes(:advisories).published.collect(&:id)};0 but it returns platforms, I want advisories in output, the output stored in temp variable.

Comment: You should always specify what version of Rails you are using so that we know which features you can use.

Answer (score 0):

There are three glaring performance issues in your example.

First, you are iterating the records using `each` which means that you are loading the entire record set into memory at once. If you must iterate records in this way you should always use [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) so it is [done in batches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20532353/1249).

Second, every iteration of your `each` loop is performing an additional SQL call to get its results. You want to limit SQL calls to the bare minimum.

Third, you are instantiating entire Rails models simply to collect a single value, which is very wasteful. **Instantiating Rails models is expensive**.

I'm going to solve these problems in two ways. First, construct an ActiveRecord relation that will access all the data you need in one query. Second, use [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) to grab the id you need without paying the model instantiation cost.

You didn't specify what `published` is doing so I am going to assume it is a scope on `Advisory`. You also left out some of the data model so I am going to have to make assumptions about your join models.

```
advisory_ids = AdvisoryAdvisoryPlatform
  .where(advisory_platform_id: current_user.company.advisory_platforms)
  .where(advisory_id: Advisory.published)
  .pluck(:advisory_id)
```

If you pass a `Relation` object as the value of a field, ActiveRecord will convert it into a subquery.

So

```
where(advisory_id: Advisory.published)
```

is analogous to

```
WHERE advisory_id IN (SELECT id FROM advisories WHERE published = true)
```

(or whatever it is `published` is doing).